# Raspberry Pi Zero W v1.1 fried

Tags: pi-zero-w, rip

I tried all things described on [this page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71968/dead-usb-otg-in-pi-zero-w), but to no avail.

I was using it with the adafruit's LCD TFT display, when it got really hot and I unplugged it. When it cooled, it didn't turn on anymore. I left it be for few hours and tried again, and it booted normally, but I don't have the USB connectivity anymore. I can see the console waiting for the login on the LCD, but nothing I can do. I can connect to the Pi via the SPI interface on the GPIO.

Few things I tried:

- Tried another cable
- Changed power supply
- Tried another device
- Checked the `dmesg` (no output on either plug or unplug)
- `lsusb` shows `Linux usb hub`
- Plugged it into a computer, with or without the SD card, but it's not detected. (Tried it with both 3.0 and 2.0 USBs and I'm running Arch)
- I tried connecting to the WiFi, but the `raspi-config` doesn't like SPI and it's interface is so broken, that I can't connect to the WiFi correctly.

Few questions:

- Is there a way for me to check if the WiFi and BT are fried as well?
- Would there be another USB line I could use to connect another USB?
- Can I connect USB via GPIO pins?
- How can I connect to the WiFi/BT without using the `raspi-config`?

## EDIT

There was no smell of burned components, so the damage couldn't have been big.

## EDIT N°2

`ip link` outputs the following

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9e:a7:8c:4c:a0:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:aa:df:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

USB is probably listed, because I have `g_ether` enabled.
This is the `dmesg` output while booting

```
[    5.961838] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.978414] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    7.743876] dwc2 20980000.usb: 20980000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
[    7.803827] dwc2 20980000.usb: Linked as a consumer to regulator.0
[    7.853668] dwc2 20980000.usb: 20980000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
[    8.133784] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm=1
[    8.144998] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm_clock_gating=1
[    8.157220] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter besl=1
[    8.168333] dwc2 20980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter hird_threshold_en=1
[    8.345675] systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[    8.418966] dwc2 20980000.usb: EPs: 8, dedicated fifos, 4080 entries in SPRAM
[    8.440221] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    8.501712] dwc2 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    8.577613] dwc2 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    8.641440] dwc2 20980000.usb: irq 33, io mem 0x20980000
[    8.714585] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.19
[    8.727683] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    8.739464] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    8.748646] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.75+ dwc2_hsotg
[    8.758866] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    9.003268] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.073894] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    9.358622] using random self ethernet address
[    9.367571] using random host ethernet address
[    9.435018] usb0: HOST MAC c6:a3:67:95:8b:f5
[    9.473817] usb0: MAC 9e:a7:8c:4c:a0:ef
[    9.481878] using random self ethernet address
[    9.490463] using random host ethernet address
[    9.573796] g_ether gadget: Ethernet Gadget, version: Memorial Day 2008
[    9.584569] g_ether gadget: g_ether ready
[    9.592394] dwc2 20980000.usb: bound driver g_ether
[   10.301030] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

I'm guessing that it does recognise  the OTG adapter and the USB hub with one port, but I have no idea if that means that it's going to work.

Comment: *"so the damage couldn't have been big"* -> The entire thing could be destroyed without smoke or a burnt smell.  *"lsusb shows Linux usb hub"* -> That's just a software entity. If that's all it shows, the USB is wrecked.   You should edit in the output of `ip link` (if there's no `wlan0`, the Wifi is wrecked, at this point you probably want to splurge for a replacement).

Comment: I was planning on ordering a new one in few days. I'll check the `ip link` as soon as I get home

Comment: @goldilocks I've updated the output with more info, namely `ip link` and `dmesg` outputs.

Comment: So right now all that's wrong is you can't plug a keyboard in because the USB seems not to work?

Comment: Correct! Nothing plugged into the USB works. Just like it's not recognised.

Comment: If the only USB port is missing, that's a bit worrying, as there's many USB peripheries, that one might want to use with the RPi, but now can't. @goldilocks